# Danger? I am trying to access a site that has Google Captcha

Tags: anonymity

Can Google Captcha trace tor users? It asked me to copy and past this and that bla bla bla. But it's from Google. Am I being tricked into revealing my IP?

Answer (score 1):

Google has seen some suspicious traffic from the exit node your using.
While you don't log-in into accounts with that you have been entering without Tor and other stuff like that, you are anonymous.
Google is just checking if you are the bot or a human.
If you want to be sure that you are indeed anonymous, press Ctrl+Shift+U or press `New identity`.